# Maximize the DV for a GLM model given constraints on inputs

Tags: r, optimization, glm

I have some purchasing data for my client base for the previous month which includes one row for each client, with a demographic score, two different types of marketing treatment, and whether the outcome was a purchase or not.

```
set.seed(124)
df <- data.frame(
demographic=rnorm(100),
treatment1=sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE),
treatment2=sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE),
purchase=rep(c(0,1),50))
```

Resulting in a table looking like this:

```
head(df, 3)
  demographic treatment1 treatment2 purchase
1 -1.38507062        3        3        0
2  0.03832318        9        8        1
3 -0.76303016        1        0        0
```

And a simple logit model

```
> fit <- glm(purchase ~ ., data = df, family = "binomial")
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = purchase ~ ., family = "binomial", data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.60111  -1.14960   0.01679   1.14923   1.66246  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.75708    0.48349  -1.566    0.117
demographic  0.34709    0.23978   1.447    0.148
treatment1   0.04108    0.06600   0.622    0.534
treatment2   0.10746    0.06975   1.541    0.123
```

Assuming that I trust the model and have appropriate measures of fit, I'm interested in generating a plan for the next month that maximizes the number of positive outcomes (purchase == 1) given that I must perform the same # of total treatments or less. My constraint, or budget, is thus given by:

```
> sum(df$treatment1) + sum(df$treatment2)
[1] 1012
```

This assumes cost is equal for both treatments so my total count of treatments must not exceed 1012. How can I generate a newdf which would maximize the count of positive conversions given by predict.glm()? This would include the same clients, so the demographic score for each row should remain the same.

Comment: Do you have the same number of observations and `demographic` characteristics in the upcoming month?

Comment: Yes, assuming the same client base / rows, question updated.